# Routing between devices connected to WiFi Hotspot

Tags: android, wireless-hotspot

I am using a HTC One X9 with Android v6.0 patched Oct 2016.

I can connect a PC and a tablet to the hotspot and access the internet.

But the tablet can't access websites hosted on the PC. I tried using a friend's 4G mobile broadband modem and the tablet can access the websites. I guess I am looking for some way to enable routing between devices connected to the same hotspot. I did check with ping and there seems to be no route active between devices at the moment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google hairpin NAT. This question has been answered dozens of times here.

Comment: Ok, I have followed up on your suggestion and researched hairpin NAT.  I understand how you might be able to configure them on a regular computer, But I still have been unable to find any links to how it could be implemented on Android.  As for the question being answered dozens of times, I couldn't' find any such answers.  Perhaps you could provide links to some of them.